# Cannot Deserialise Json array into type string

Tags: json, winforms, c#-4.0

Following id my piece of code which deserialise Json string.

```
  response = "{\"success\":\"yes\",\"error\":\"\",\"message\":\"\",\"arguments\":[{\"id\":\"72820\",\"rowNo\":\"1\",\"userId\":\"40\",\"entityId\":\"3486\",\"value\":\"search Panel\",\"typeCategory\":\"3\"}]}";

        erpAPIResponse basicResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<erpAPIResponse>(response);
```

Result is JSON string which is deserialised into erpAPIResponse.

My erpAPIResponse is as follows:

```
public string success { get; set; } // getting and setting the success
    public string error { get; set; } // getting and setting the error
    public string message { get; set; } // getting and setting the message
    public string arguments { get; set; } // getting and setting the arguments
   // public string result { get; set; }
```

I have verify json through JSON Lint and it is saying it is valid JSON string. So why i am getting this errorr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your json structure is like below:

```
{
    "success": "yes",
    "error": "",
    "message": "",
    "arguments": [
        {
            "id": "72820",
            "rowNo": "1",
            "userId": "40",
            "entityId": "3486",
            "value": "search Panel",
            "typeCategory": "3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here you cannot deserialize the `arguments` array in a string. So you need to redefine the `erpAPIResponse` class like below using [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com) utility:

```
public class erpAPIResponse
{
    public string success { get; set; }
    public string error { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<Argument> arguments { get; set; }
}

public class Argument
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string rowNo { get; set; }
    public string userId { get; set; }
    public string entityId { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string typeCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Now you should have no problem deserializing with your original statements:

```
response = "{\"success\":\"yes\",\"error\":\"\",\"message\":\"\",\"arguments\":[{\"id\":\"72820\",\"rowNo\":\"1\",\"userId\":\"40\",\"entityId\":\"3486\",\"value\":\"search Panel\",\"typeCategory\":\"3\"}]}";

erpAPIResponse basicResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<erpAPIResponse>(response);
```

Comment: i want arguments in string and then i will deserialise it again

Comment: I have successfully deserialized the code like above. Would you please point to the specific error where you have stuck?